# mercurial (hg) modify incoming changeset date in a hook on a push

Tags: mercurial

Using Mercurial.

Does anyone know if there is a good way to modify a changeset's commit date via a hook, such as pretxnchangegroup, during an incoming push ?

Once a change comes in to a repo the changeset dates are always the commit dates. I'd like to changes/override these dates to the 'push' dates instead -- via a hook during a push.

It seems that ctx.date() is a tuple and immutable.

Thank you.

Comment: If you do this, the commit hashes will change and the pusher will have to pull down the same changesets again with new hashes and strip out their old ones. They'll also have to rebase any work they haven't yet pushed onto the new changesets.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try. You wouldn't have a small example to prove this would you ?

Comment: Sorry, I've never tried because in most cases, it would be a bad idea. There's always an exception to the rule.

Answer (score -1):

Commit date, author as well as the patch content itself make up the changesetID. Thus changing either will change the changesetID - and as such they cannot be modified on an existing changeset.

Mercurial, like most modern VCS, is a *distributed* version control system, thus the commit date is recorded as the time received to any arbitrary repository is arbitrary at best while the commit time and date are global as they are recorded once only and don't change on propagation through different repositories.

You should ask yourself why you need that. If you worked on a patch series which you then want to push to an authorative project repo, do the changes before you push by updating (commit --amend) the still-draft changesets on the author's side. You can even integrate a hook server-side to enforce this policy which checks the age of the commits received and deny push when they are older than XX minutes.

However if you really want to realise the bad idea you ask about:

If you operate on a non-publishing repository, and if you receive draft changesets, then you might get away with creating new commits with an updated timestamp from the changesets you just received, obsoleting the old ones. Using the evolve extension might make this work a lot easier.

If you receive public changesets, or if your repository is publishing, then doing these things with `rebase` and `commit --amend` would seem very troublesome and I would not enjoy contributing as I would end up with everything I wrote and pushed duplicate in my local repository.

Comment: Thanks all. I run `hg commit --amend -d yesterday` (for example) in the ws and see what you mean about the hash changing. How would I do the same in a hook ?  I mean how to simply change the date of an incoming cset a in hook on push (not using hg commit --amend). A very simple example. I am familiar with hooks set up, but looking for a way to mutate the date. I realize this will also change the hash but just want to see it with my own eyes. Thanks again.

Comment: push and pull exchange changesets between repositories and don't alter anything on existing changesets. They are used to *sync* repositories. Thus altering a commit on push or pull is out of question.